# How to parse cryptography x509 extension

Tags: python, class, object, cryptography

I have an x509 cert that I am trying to parse (specifically the KeyUsage) which appears to be of type extensions.KeyUsage (from extensions.py) in the [python cryptography module](https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/).

`type(KeyUsage)`

returns

`<class 'cryptography.x509.extensions.KeyUsage'>`

The full extension string returned from

`KeyUsage = certDecoded.extensions.get_extension_for_oid(ExtensionOID.KEY_USAGE)`

looks like:

`KeyUsage: <Extension(oid=<ObjectIdentifier(oid=2.5.29.15, name=keyUsage)>, critical=True, value=<KeyUsage(digital_signature=True, content_commitment=False, key_encipherment=True, data_encipherment=False, key_agreement=False, key_cert_sign=False, crl_sign=False, encipher_only=False, decipher_only=False)>)>`

calling `KeyUsage.value` returns

`<KeyUsage(digital_signature=True, content_commitment=False, key_encipherment=True, data_encipherment=False, key_agreement=False, key_cert_sign=False, crl_sign=False, encipher_only=False, decipher_only=False)>`

Which returns a the type above (extensions.KeyUsage)

Looking at the [source for the class](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/blob/main/src/cryptography/x509/extensions.py) it 'appears' (to me) to return a string (so thats my first misunderstanding...) because I thought extensions were iterable according to the docs.

However, can anyone help me understand (firstly) the object type, so I can feed myself in the future, and (secondly) some suggestions on how I should parse this; say into a simple dict object please?

Comment: If the object supports the mapping protocol (many do) you can call the built-in function `vars()` on an instance and get back a dict.

Comment: Thanks! - this does what i need.